# ANTLR not recognising the token at the beginning

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, lexer

I am a beginner in ANTLR, and i want to make a program that detects variables. For that I wrote the following ANTLR code, but when I test it using `grun`, it gives me an error `line 1:0 token recognition error at: 'p'` on entering input `p=10`. I am unable to understand why does this not work.

```
grammar rules;
/*
*   Parser Rules
*/

addition : NUMBER PLUS NUMBER;
assign : VARIABLE ASSIGNMENT NUMBER;

/*
*   Lexer Rules
*/

VARIABLE : [a-zA-Z_]+;
NUMBER : [0-9]+ ;
WHITESPACE : [ \n\t\r]+ -> skip ;
NEWLINE: '\n';
PLUS : '+';
ASSIGNMENT : '=';
```

The rule for addition works fine, but the assign is not working.
The command I am running on terminal is `antlr4 rules.g4;grun rules assign -tokens` and after that I input `p=10` for testing, but still it does not work and shows me `line 1:0 token recognition error at: 'p'` error.

Comment: Do you get any messages/warnings from ANTLR? You might be missing a top-level rule `expression := addition | assign`

Comment: @jurez I'm sorry. I was missing compiling the java files in the above command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The command I am running on terminal is `antlr4 rules.g4;grun rules assign -tokens`

`antlr4` will generate Java source files from your grammar. `grun` will be accessing `rulesParser.class` and `rulesLexer.class`. What you're missing is the step in between where you use `javac` to compile the generated source files to class files.

Since you're not getting any errors about `grun` being unable to find the classes, you probably still have class files left over from the last time you ran `javac`. So `grun` is executing those old files, which apparently don't include anything that matches letters yet (or at least not the letter p). Compiling your source files with `javac` should fix this problem.